# Lenses and prisms with sum types

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

This code won't compile.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data A = A { _a1 :: B, _a2 :: Int }
makeLenses ''A

data B = B1 { _b1 :: Int } | B2
makeLenses ''B
```

The error is `amy.hs:5:21: Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘B’`. I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to do something like this, or do I need to write my own lenses for `B`?
2. Given an `A`, I would like to apply a function to the `b1` field, if that field exists. I think this is a job for prisms, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange your program as follows

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data A = A { _a1 :: B, _a2 :: Int }
data B = B1 { _b1 :: Int } | B2

makeLenses ''A 
makeLenses ''B
```

The issue has to do with staging order of Template Haskell (and in this case it's possibly a bug).

Observe that `makeLenses ''B` creates a `Traversal` for the `_b1` field because it only appears in one of the two constructors.

```
b1 :: Traversal' B Int
```

If you were to use Prisms, as well, you'd add

```
makePrisms ''B
```

which would produce

```
_B1 :: Prism' B Int
_B2 :: Prism' B ()
```

Comment: Not only did you answer the question I asked, but you anticipated and answered the next two questions I would have asked next!